# What are these stripes in swimming pool light lenses called which make the LEDs seem as if they are pointing towards us, no matter where we are?

Tags: diffraction, lenses

[image]

What are these stripes in swimming pool light lenses called which  make the LEDs seem as if they are pointing towards us, no matter where we are? How do these stripes work?

Also, should their angle be perpendicular to ground or parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those stripes are *lenses* that have been molded into the clear plastic or glass that protects the LED's from the water. But instead of being circular lenses, they are stretched out in one direction into what you call "stripes". Such an arrangement is called a *cylindrical lens* and is used when you want to control the spread of a light beam in just one direction instead of two.

In this case, the objective of the lens is to spread out the light beam in the horizontal plane so it appears to be beamed sideways- and hence it seems to be focused on you no matter where you are located within that horizontal plane.